# How do I delete a specific file in recycler view of Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-adapter

I am working on this diary app on Android studio and I want people to be able to delete their entries, but I have no idea how.

This is the TextListAdapter (recyclerview):

```
public class TextListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TextListAdapter.TextViewHolder>{

    private File[] allTextFiles;
    private TimeAgo timeAgo;

    private onTextItemListClick onTextItemListClick;



    public TextListAdapter(File[] allTextFiles, onTextItemListClick onTextItemListClick) {
        this.allTextFiles = allTextFiles;
        this.onTextItemListClick = onTextItemListClick;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TextViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_text_item, parent, false);
        timeAgo = new TimeAgo();
        return new TextViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TextListAdapter.TextViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.cardText.setText(allTextFiles[position].getName());
        holder.textCardTitle.setText(timeAgo.getTimeAgo(allTextFiles[position].lastModified()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return allTextFiles.length;
    }




    //Inner Class

    public class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private final Context context;
        //Adding components
        private TextView textCardTitle;
        private Button cardText;
        private MaterialButton textCardBtn;
        private String recordFile;
        private ImageButton deleteText;


        public TextViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textCardTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_card_title);
            cardText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
            textCardBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_card_btn);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            deleteText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_menu_btn);

            textCardBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


        }





        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onTextItemListClick.onClickListener(allTextFiles[getAdapterPosition()], getAdapterPosition());
            final Intent intent;
            intent =  new Intent(context, DiaryEntry.class);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, cardText.getText());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    //Interface
    public interface onTextItemListClick{
        void onClickListener(File file, int position);
    }
    
    
}
```

And this is the fragment it comes from:

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        
        textList = view.findViewById(R.id.text_list_view);


        //Reversing audioList
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        textList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


        String path = getActivity().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        File directory = new File(path);
        allTextFiles = directory.listFiles();

        textListAdapter = new TextListAdapter(allTextFiles, this);


        textList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        textList.setAdapter(textListAdapter);


    }
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need set the clickListener inside TextViewHolder for deleteText

like this.

```
  deleteText.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then inside onClick of your function of the Adaptor

```
int position = getAdaptorPosition;
allTextFiles.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Hopefully, it will work inform me if found any error i would love to help you.

Comment: First of all thank you for the help @Haris Abdullah! Unfortunatley the .remove() does not work for some reason. It only gives me the option to "rename reference". Do you have any other way? Here is the code I wrote that I got from you. I had to use a seperate method because I already used onClick for the textCardBtn: `deleteText.setOnClickListener(removeText());
        }

        private View.OnClickListener removeText() {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            allTextFiles.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }` Once Again Thank you

Comment: Brother this  is not the best way to call set on click listener try this `
deleteText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
 int position = getAdapterPosition();          
   allTextFiles.remove(position);          
   notifyItemRemoved(position);  
}`Try this brother

Comment: Thank you I will try it soon.